# spc0224 Module GeneXus not available for C# Web environment

Tags: genexus, genexus15

Acabo de empezar en GeneXus 15 e hice una KB basica con una transición y aplicando el Work With for Web y para Smart Devices y al momento de presionar F5 me sale el error mostrado en el titulo. ¿Alguna solución?
Anexo una captura de pantalla con los errores.
[image: El mismo error se repite en todos.]

Comment: Te sugiero que ejecutes un `genexus.exe /install` por línea de comandos y luego vuelvas a intentar.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo inconveniente, por lo que ejecutando por línea de comandos "genexus.exe /install" habiendo cerrado Genexus previamente, quedó resuelto!